# Custom function for annotate

Tags: python, django, orm

I am trying to extract records with my Django ORM Model:

```
users =   User.objects.values( "first_name", "last_name" ).annotate( user_level=custom_levels( F("user_level" ) ) );
```

The model is represented by:

- first_name
- last_name
- user_level: it may be *[1]* or *[1,13]* (it comes from saving a MultipleSelect throught forms.py)

**Goal:**
My goal is to process *user_level* in the query in order to transform those ids in text (I have a dict key:value with those ids). For that I was thinking of writing a function, *custom_level*, to process the pairing job.

I am using *annotate()* but I am not really sure of its correct use.
How would you process the pairing between ids and text in order to get a single text line?

Any clue?
Thank you

Comment: what is ```custom_levels```?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I didn't explain in the original post. Edited. Basically: custom_level is supposed to be the function I am writing to process the pairing job among ids.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see a reason why you should do it on ORM level. Why don't you just make it with model's property, which would transform this field value onto desired? Like this:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
# ...

    @property
    def user_level_description(self):
        level_descriptions = {
            1: "Level One",
            2: "Level Two",
            # ...
        }
        return ", ".join(level_descriptions[level] for level in self.user_level)
```

Comment: Thank you for you super advise! My aim is to do it at ORM level because your _level_descriptions_ is retrieved by another table/model (I have a table where I store id_level and level_name) so I need to pair this ids to the level name contained into the table. I am worried about doing so into the model because the model is declared into another app into the project and I may create loops, but I may try...how would you suggest to implement it?

Comment: Furthermore does your suggested _for level in self.user_level_ work with strings as _[1,2]_ (squared brakets included)

Comment: If you store this information at DB, you possibly should update your question. In your question, your wording looks like you have `dict key:value with those ids` in python code. I supposed that you have [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield](`ArrayField`) (link in case if you're working with PostgreSQL) with those IDs, not a plain string, in that case, my implementation would work. About doing that on the ORM level, the best approach would be to go with [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/](`ManyToMany`) relation.